# How to create LTspice hierarchical blocks/sub-circuits/custom components? "Missing schematic of the hierarchy: "

Tags: simulation, ltspice

I have been using LTspice with groups of components copied and pasted from previous models and this is getting quite ridiculous. I want to be able to create hierarchical schematics but every time I try, I keep getting the error "Missing schematic of the hierarchy: XXXX" from LTspice when running the simulation.

Here are the detailed steps I took (supported by various sources online):

1. Created a folder in my backed-up drive H: named LTspiceLib
2. In LTspice, Tools > Control Panel > Sym & Lib search paths, added the absolute path to LTspiceLib in both Symbol and Library. Applied changes.
3. Created a schematic saved under the name "spdt" in LTspiceLib, as shown:
   [image]
4. Created a symbol saved under the name "spdt" in LTspiceLib, as shown:
   [image]
5. In the symbol editor, Edit > Attributes, selected "Block" (although I also tried Cell). Left all fields blank (although I also tried typing "spdt" in Value). Saved.
6. Created a new schematic in which I added the component spdt. Right clicking on it allows be to open both the symbol and schematic without issue, but I can't run a simulation.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best practices for using subcircuits and hierarchical blocks in LTspice](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/409581/best-practices-for-using-subcircuits-and-hierarchical-blocks-in-ltspice)

Comment: In case you find that answer too long, here's the TLDR: hierarchical schematics need the symbol to be of type "block", not "cell" (you got that), and both the symbols and their hierarchical schematics need to be in the same place as the top-level schematic. Using libraries is not a hierarchical design (as the error message suggests).

Comment: Thanks for your comments. This is actually much clearer, as I had stumbled upon this thread but I thought putting the Symbol and Schematic files in the search paths was sufficient to put it into scope. Do you mean I will always have to copy and paste the custom components I use from my libraries into my project folders? Sounds like a real caveat of this (otherwise great) software.